# Positioning an ordered sequence of intervals for maximum alignment with another sequence of fixed intervals

Tags: algorithm, intervals

I have two sequences of intervals.

The first is fixed and non-overlapping, so something like:

```
[1..10], [12..15], [23..56], [72..89], ...
```

The second is not fixed, so it's just an ordered list of interval lengths:

```
[7, 2, 5, 26, ...]
```

The task at hand is to:

- Place every interval from the second list at a given starting point, so that the second list becomes a list of fixed, non-overlapping intervals much like the first, while preserving its order
- Find the alignment that minimizes the amount of integers that are in some interval from one of the lists but not in any interval from the other list

Very simple example:

```
[25..26], [58..68], [74..76], [78..86]

[10, 12]
```

The optimal solution is to place the interval of length 10 at [58..68] and the interval of length 12 at [74..86] which results in only the numbers 25, 26, and 77 being in one list but not the other.

The only thing I've come up with that seems mildly helpful is that if I lay down the intervals in order, I know how many 'penalties' the interval I've already created, so I have an upper bound for the score, which means I have an admissible heuristic and I can do A* search instead of looking at the entire tree. However, the total range of numbers spans from 0 to about 34M, so I'd like something better.

Any help would be hot!

Comment: Interesting problem. It's not quite the same as best-fit memory allocation since you want best fit for the entire set rather than for just one length at a time, but it's similar in that your available ranges are non-overlapping. You don't actually care which block is used, so equal-length blocks are fungible; that should let you do a simpler search and then expand the results.  Precalculating what combined lengths exist (ie, knowing in the trivial case that if any range can accept a length of 24 that's immediately an optimal solution) might also speed things up. ... Have fun....

Comment: I smell dynamic programming..

Comment: re: dynamic programming, I don't see it.
If the recursive function is defined as finding the best match once you've already fixed one interval, then the problem doesn't have identical sub-problems (ie placing the other intervals is a different task depending on where you put the first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's a half-thought-out answer. It should work in polynomial time, but I haven't bothered checking what the index is. It may well be possible to get a better index than the answer as outlined here. The details are left as an exercise to the reader :-) I hope it's not too unclear.

I'll define the **score** of a solution as the number of integers which appear in both lists of intervals. Let f(i,m) be the highest score it's possible to get using just the first i interval lengths, subject to the condition that none of your intervals goes above m. The function f, for fixed i, is essentially a (non-strictly) increasing function from the integers to a bounded subset of the integers. Therefore:

- all values of f(i,m), for m > 0, are equal, with finitely many exceptions;
- all values of f(i,m), for m < 0, are equal, with finitely many exceptions.

This means it's possible to represent all values of f(i,m) using a finite data structure (still considering a fixed value of i).

Now let F(i) be the value of this data structure representing all values of f(i,m). I claim that, given F(i), it is possible to calculate F(i+1). To do this, we only need to answer the following question for all x: If I place the new interval at x, how good is the best solution I can get? But we know what this is - it's just f(i,x) + the score we've got from this interval.

So if n is the number of intervals in the second list, the score of the best solution will be F(n).

To actually find the solution, you could work backwards from this.

You know what's the best score you can get. Say it's s_0. Then put the last interval as far left as possible, subject to the condition that it allows you to score s_0. That is, find the smallest m such that f(n,m) = s_0; and place the interval such that it only just stays inside the bound at m.

Then, let s_1 be the score you need to get from all the other intervals in order to get a total of s_0. Place the next-last interval as far left as possible, subject to the condition that you can still score s_1. That is, find the smallest m such that f(n,m) = s_1; and place the interval such that it only just stays inside the bound at m.

And so on...

Comment: There's a couple things I'm not wrapping my head around here, but mostly I don't see how this guarantees optimality at all.


You know f(0, m) for any m: it's 0. You can get get f(1, m) by seeing what the best score you can get is adding the 1st interval, because there's no ambiguity as to where it's allowed to go. But for f(2, m), the best score you can get by adding the 2nd interval depends on where you put the 1st one.


Which part of your algorithm actually bounds the score to anything else than just sum(length(interval) for interval in intervals)?

Comment: Misphrased that: ignore the last question about the bound.

Essentially my problem is that to get from f(i) to f(i + 1) you need to iterate through a list of all the optimal solutions for f(i) to use them as a base for adding interval i + 1, since overlap is forbidden. The list of optimal solutions grows exponentially.

Comment: I'm starting with the (slightly) simpler task of finding how good the best solutions are, without actually finding the solutions. Suppose we know F(i), and want to calculate F(i+1). For any m, we can find the best possible score subject to the condition that the new interval starts at m; it's just f(i+m) + (score from new interval). **NB: We only needed f(i,m), not details of the solution.** Call this score g(i,m). Let w be new interval's width; then the bound for such solutions is m+w. So f(i+1,m'+w) is the maximum of all g(i,m) for m <= m'.

Comment: OK, I hadn't understood that you're forcing the new intervals to start after m, but then you don't guarantee optimality.

With [1..2], [4..5], [7..8], [10..11], [13..14], [16..17], [19..21] and 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, we have F(1) is f(1, 21) = 3. Then all F(n) for n > 1 are still 3. Point being: getting the best score for just one interval might lead you to lose the chance to get the best score when you add more down the line, so this doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Firstly, don't worry that my numbers may be out by 1. I didn't work out all details before. F(i) isn't just one value of f(i,m). It's a data structure telling you all values of f(i,m). So F(1) tells us: f(1,1)=0, f(1,2)=1, f(1,3)=2, ... , f(1,21)=2, f(1,22)=3. From this we can get all values of g(1,m). E.g. for g(1,15) we place interval 2 at [15,16] (score +1); therefore best possible overall score = (best possible score from interval 1) + 1 = f(1,15)+1=2+1=3. Also g(1,14)=3; but g(1,13)=f(1,13)+2=4. Then f(2,17)=max_{m<=15}g(1,m), which happens to be 4. So we can calculate f(2,m) for all m.